# Undefined property: stdClass error, Whats wrong with my query?

Tags: php, sql

when

```
$domain_id = $db->getAll("SELECT `domain_id` FROM `".PREFIX."domains`");
```

in a loop

```
<?php echo $domain_id[$i]->domain_id ?>
```

Works perfectly and echo domain ids

But

```
$domain_assign_to = $db->getAll("SELECT `custom_for` FROM `".PREFIX."domains`");
```

in a loop

```
<?php echo $domain_assign_to[$i]->domain_assign_to ?>
```

do not work and gives Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$domain_assign_to

`custom_for` have user's usernames.
`domain_id` is int and `custom_for` is a varchar

what i am doing wrong here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Your select query says 'custom_for' ?

Comment: can you `print_r($domain_assign_to);`

Comment: @chandresh_cool, yes its a column which have user's usernames.

Comment: Then how you will get `domain_assign_to` in that array if you are not asking for that

Comment: Hope you got your answer.

Comment: `<?php echo $domain_assign_to[$i]->custom_for ?>` will work

Comment: @Akshay , yes i can its giving me all rows .

Comment: can you add that array in your question?

Comment: @Akshay OMG can not believe how i missed this, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should replace this:**

```
$domain_assign_to = $db->getAll("SELECT `custom_for`FROM `".PREFIX."domains`");
```

**With**

```
$domain_assign_to = $db->getAll("SELECT `custom_for`,'domain_assign_to' FROM `".PREFIX."domains`"); // if domain_assign_to exist in table
```

**OR**

```
<?php echo $domain_assign_to[$i]->domain_assign_to ?>
```

**With**

```
<?php echo $domain_assign_to[$i]-> custom_for?>
```

Comment: <?php echo $domain_assign_to[$i]-> custom_for?> worked, thank you.

Comment: Happy coding !!